# Image not showing when path is put as URL in Safari, loads fine in Chrome

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, safari, ios

See: https://mattressesforless.net/images/back2shool.jpg

Try loading that directly in Chrome on desktop. Loads fine. Doesn't load in Safari on desktop (nor in chrome/safari on iOS).

I know path is correct since it loads fine in chrome on desktop.

Googling yielded this: https://www.fngtps.com/2010/mobile-safari-image-resource-limit-workaround/

Only issue is I'm loading the image directly, and it also happens on desktop, in where the restrictions doesn't happen. I opened console in browsers to see if any errors -- nada. I'm at a loss as to how to explain this.

**Client information:**

Mobile OS: iOS 11

Desktop: macOS sierra, Safari 11.0 and Chrome 61.0.3163

**Server information:**

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Web Server: Apache/2.4.7

Comment: Your image has the header FFD8 FFE1, which indicates a jpeg/exif image, normally reserved for digital photos. I don't know why Safari would have an issue with that, but try removing the EXIF information and see if it makes a difference. By the way, I would recommend saving this file as a PNG from the original source since it is mostly text.

Comment: Stripped EXIF, strip was successful, but it also displayed an error: "Error                           : File format error".  So I ran the identify command, which said: "identify: Corrupt JPEG data: 5 extraneous bytes before marker 0xee `back2shool.jpg' @ warning/jpeg.c/JPEGWarningHandler/352."  I ran identify on the original file (that still had exif data), same result.  Not sure how to proceed from here.  Still no problem opening the file to see it, Safari just can't read it.   I do not have access to the original files.  What's the best way to remove those extra bytes?

Comment: I opened the file in Gimp, saved it as jpg overwriting the original file, then checked the file with identify -- no errors.  Opening fine in Safari now.  It was those extra bytes.  There's alot of files with those same bytes, is there a quick way to clean up those files via command line?

Comment: You can try using ExifTool as referenced in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654281/how-to-remove-exif-data-without-recompressing-the-jpeg). I don't know if it will fix the file format or not.

Comment: It didn't.  I ended up manually going through each file with Gimp and overwriting it.  I was able to recover all of the JPG files, but the PNG files were not recoverable (they wouldn't open in Gimp).

Answer (score 0):

Since the file can be opened by Gimp, just open it in Gimp, click file and click "Overwrite file".  It'll overwrite and save.  Re-upload the file and overwrite the original file on the server.  Refresh Safari browser; it'll now load the file with no further issues.

**Note**: if Gimp isn't able to open the file, then this solution will not work to fix the issue.